# POST :create rspec controller testing error, wrong number of arguments 2 for 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller

I'm trying to test my Post_comments#create action in the controller specs with rspec and I keep getting this error message:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create, :post_id => post.to_param, :post_comment => attributes_for(:post_comment, comment: "New")

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
 # ./spec/controllers/post_comments_controller_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My Post Comments controller:

```
 class PostCommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_todo_list

  def index
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.all
  end

  def show
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.new
  end

  def edit
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.new(post_comment_params)
    if 
      @post_comment.save
      redirect_to post_post_comments_path
      flash[:success] = "Comment added successfully!"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Comment could not be saved"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.find(params[:id])
    if
      @post_comment.update(post_comment_params)
      redirect_to post_post_comment_path
      flash[:success] = "Comment successfully updated"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Comment could not be updated"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.find(params[:id])
    @post_comment.destroy

    redirect_to post_post_comments_path
    flash[:success] = "The comment was successfully deleted"
  end
end

private

  def find_todo_list
    @post = Post.find_by(params[:post_id])
  end

  def post_comment_params
    params.require(:post_comment).permit(:comment)
  end
```

My controller spec that keeps failing:

```
 describe "POST #create" do
context "flash messages" do
  let(:post) {create(:post)}

  it "sets flash success" do
    post :create, :post_id => post.to_param, :post_comment => attributes_for(:post_comment, comment: "New")
    expect(flash[:success]).to eq("Comment added successfully!")
  end
end
```

end

I'm using factory girl so here is my factory for post comments, which has a belongs_to association with a post...duh

```
  factory :post_comment do
    comment "Post comment"
    post
  end
```

Any help would really help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let(:post) {create(:post)}
# ...
post :create
```

`let` is a fancy way of defining a method on the current RSpec example. `post` is now a method that accepts 0 arguments, thus the message `wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)`.

Try naming your Post object something else.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly the problem. @zetetic